# postfixでキューに溜まっている件数のみを知る方法

Tags: postfix

Postfixで、キューに溜まっている件数のみを知る方法を知りたいのですが、良い方法はありますでしょうか？

/usr/sbin/postqueue -p

では、キューに溜まっているメール内容まで出力されてしまうので、これではなく、件数のみが知りたいのです。

負荷が少なく、軽い方法があればお教えください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

単純に件数だけでいいなら`postqueue -p | tail -n 1`でいいと思います。Requestが件数のことです。

また、似たような質問がServerfaultにありました。それによると`qshape`というコマンドも利用できるそうです。

https://serverfault.com/questions/58196/how-do-i-check-the-postfix-queue-size

qshapeについては以下のようなページもありました。
http://www.postfix-jp.info/trans-2.3/jhtml/QSHAPE_README.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！
qshapeというのは知りませんでした。とても参考になりました。